# How can I set a UINavigationController as my initial screen when I have a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that loads a UINavigationController for each of its tab. The first tab is obviously my initial screen, however I don't want the tab-bar to be visible for this screen.

Maybe my approach is wrong. How can I make sure that a UINavigationController is shown as my initial screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whichever view you put in `[window addSubview:]` in your app delegate will be visible on launch.  If you just want the `UINavigationController`, add its `view` property.  If your tab bar isn't visible on launch, how were you planning on making it visible?

Comment: I was hoping the user could click on a button on my UINavigationControllers view which would then launch a view with the tabbar